# How can I get an array located in other component? (template, *ngComponentOutlet and AngularMaterialDialog)

Tags: angular, angular-material

*Angular 7, Angular Material 7*

GalleryComponent where images are listed and user can select some of them:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-gallery',
  template: `

    <mat-card *ngFor="let file of files" (click)="toggleSelect(file)">
      <img mat-card-image [src]="file.url">
    </mat-card>

  `
})
export class GalleryComponent {
  selected: Array<FileDetails> = [];
  files: Array<FileDetails> = [{url: 'someurl1'}, {url: 'someurl2'}];

  toggleSelect(file: FileDetails): void {
    const indexInArray = this.selected.findIndex(f => f === file);
    indexInArray !== -1 ? this.selected.splice(indexInArray, 1) : this.selected.push(file);
  }
}
```

In an other component (PartnersEditTableComponent), I would like to re-use Gallery Component in a template, opening in a modal/dialog (Angular Material Dialog).

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-partners-edit-table',
  template: `

    <button mat-icon-button (click)="openGallery()">
      <mat-icon>collections</mat-icon>
    </button>

    <ng-template #galleryModal>
      <h2 mat-dialog-title>Gallery</h2>
      <mat-dialog-content>
        <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="GalleryComponent"></ng-container>
      </mat-dialog-content>
      <mat-dialog-actions align="end">
        <button mat-raised-button [mat-dialog-close]="false">Close</button>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" [mat-dialog-close]="GalleryComponent.selected">Select</button>
      </mat-dialog-actions>
    </ng-template>

  `
})
export class PartnersEditTableComponent {
  @ViewChild('galleryModal') private readonly galleryModal;
  GalleryComponent = GalleryComponent;

  constructor(private matDialog: MatDialog) {
  }

  openGallery(): void {
    this.matDialog.open(this.galleryModal).afterClosed().subscribe((selectedItems) => {
      if (selectedItems) {
        // do something with selectedItems array
      }
    });
  }
}
```

If the user clicks on "Select" button on dialog, I want to get "selected" array like:

```
[mat-dialog-close]="GalleryComponent.selected"
```

->

```
this.matDialog.open(this.galleryModal).afterClosed().subscribe((selectedItems) => {
  if (selectedItems) {
    // do something with selectedItems array
  }
});
```

Is this possible to do that somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data from a dialog ref with

```
this.dialogRef.close("YOUR_DATA");
```

or inside the HTML with

```
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="'YOUR_DATA'">Ok</button>
```

This however means, that your GalleryComponent needs to be aware that it is a `MatDialog`.

You can do this by injecting it with

```
  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData | any) {
  }
```

Now for you there is a tricky part, because usually you don't use a Component inside and outside of a modal. However you can achieve this, by marking the fields as optional and check them for null before usage

```
  constructor(
    @Optional() public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>,
    @Optional() @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData | any) {
  }

  onNoClick(): void {
    if (this.dialogRef)
      this.dialogRef.close("Stefan");
  }
```

You can find a working example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uy8uwe